# how to post :create from the default update url, rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but I'm somewhat new to rails and struggling to find a solution via search.

I'm implementing a message model to enable private messaging on a forum.  I have the models resource nested within a users resource.

Currently the model works, but I want to enable a user to reply to a private message directly on the message show page.  I.e users/1/messages/16 instead of users/1/messages/new.  Currently this is the default route for 'update' within the MessagesController.  Is there anyway to make the form on this page hit the 'create' action within the controller, instead of the 'update'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, I would try something like this:

On your show page just add a new form.

```
<%= form_for :message, :url => new_user_message_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

You can check the routes of your application using this command:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

I suggest you to read the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Thanks, didn't quite work as listed above, but browsing through that guide I found that <%= form_for :message, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %> did the trick.